# RAID 0+1 Transfer speed and ssd / hdd combination

Tags: ssd, raid, raid-0, transfer

can you help me choosing a raid system?

ive got raid0 on my last system (ssd) = fast transfer rates

BUT they crashed and all data went into trash.

isnt there a system that mirrors a raid0 ? (wiki says raid01 (raid 0+1))

BUT (again^^) my mirror hdds are normal hdds, so the transfer rates are not equal to the ssd.

so my question will the "system" trottle the rates to the lowest hdd? (=normal hhds?)

detailed: ssd have about 440MB/S the raptors have ~120MB/S

br
foxl

Comment: Related: [What would happen in a Software Raid 1 of one HDD and one SSD?](http://superuser.com/questions/226247/what-would-happen-in-a-software-raid-1-of-one-hdd-and-one-ssd)

Answer (score 0):

'mirror' RAID 0? RAID 0 is striping with no redundancy, if that's what you want then use RAID 0.

If you want redundancy then use any other RAID type.

If you want the speed of RAID 0 with redundancy then RAID 4, 5 or 6 (or more commonly RAID10).

RAID will always work at the slowest drives speed, that's why as a general 'rule of thumb' you use equal drives with equal storage and speeds.